# Firebase / GTM: Custom Tags

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

In a Website GTM implementation , you have the possibility to create your own custom tags using javascript, so it's easy to set up webservice calls to your own system etc by just using the GTM interface.

Now for a Firebase - GTM implemented app, are there any possibilities like this?
I saw the functioncall option, but if I get it correct, this means you need to program some methods/functions inside your app and you can call them using GTM and there's also the option to pass some params. This is not quite the same as the website-gtm tags, which we can create on the fly in GTM.

Is there any other way , without the need to redeploy your app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, since we cannot inject code into an app using GTM there are no custom tags. 
True, there is a Firebase function. Another option which has been used for a while in GTM SDK is an **image tag**. 
[image]

It lets you execute server-side code on your server or use azure function as well as firebase function

Answer (score 0):

I believe the advantage of GTM with mobile apps is that you can manage existing events and parameters by enabling or disabling them. When you release a version of your app that is logging a certain way you will not be able to change that and any users that have not updated to your new version will continue to log the same information.

Example:

```
MyApp v1.0.0
    MyEvent
        - my_param_id
        - my_param_name
        - my_param_etc
MyApp v1.0.1
    MyEvent
        - my_param_id (this is now the name)
        - my_param_etc
```

Without GTM users with 1.0.0 will still be logging in the same way it was set up at the time it was released. With GTM you will be able to filter out those events with the "trigger" to not allow those events to get logged.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while, in the meantime I have been searching myself.
It seems like the best option to manipulate stuff and execute custom tags are the Cloud Functions in Firebase that can be triggered by Firebase Events.